Significant performance drop between train and validation set
I am trying both Lgbm and RandomForest for a classification, and I observe the same problem. I am using various metaparams to prevent overfitting, such as max_depth, num_trees (keeping it small for Lgbm), reg_alpha and reg_lambda for Lgbm, etc.
In both cases, AUC drops from around 70% on the train set, to 55% on the validation (for the best params combination), and same for testing set, it is around 55%.
What I am thinking about: is there anything I can do to bring these together? Is early stopping a possibility, and what else can I try to not overfit on the training set? Obviously the learned insights don't translate out of sample.
Or could it be a more fundamental issue at an earlier step, e.g. with feature engineering, etc?

Yes, use early stopping at first. Using lower learning rates for LightGBM (and boosting in general) allows avoiding local optima too.

Talk about the class of problem you are solving, and how you split the data into train and validation.  Time series has its own rules.  might need to stratify.

In general when they disagree it means that the model-fit does not generalize, it does not handle well data outside the training set.  This might mean your learner can't do the job, but it might mean your data wasn't healthy when you supplied it.
